# Is there features about draw straight line, rectangle, pencil tool with Apache ECharts?

Tags: apache-echarts

I found the project https://github.com/svrcekmichal/react-sketchpad.
Is there features about draw straight line, rectangle, pencil tool like above project with Apache ECharts?